# Translating 8051 microcontroller C code

Tags: c, 8051

```
void extrint (void) interrupt 0 // external Interrupt to detect the heart pulse
{
  bt = tick;  // number of ticks are picked
  tick = 0;   // reset for next counting
}

void timer0 (void) interrupt 1 using 1 // Timer 0 for one second time
{
  TH0 = 0xdc; // The value is taken for Ssc/100 at crystal 11.0592MHz
  sec100++;   // It is incremented every Ssc/100 at crystal 11.0592MHz
  tick++;     // This variable counts the time period of incoming pulse in Sec/100

  if (tick >= 3500)
     {tick = 0;} // tick are limited to less than 255 for valid calculation

   if (sec100 >= 100) // 1 sec = sec100 * 100
   {
     sec++;
     sec100=0;
   }
 }
```

Can somebody explain me what the above code means and does. It was written for a 8051 microcontroller.

i got it from here 
http://www.zembedded.com/heart-rate-beats-meter-with-microcontroller-at89c51-based-heartbeat-monitor/

Comment: eh? the comments already do that....

Comment: @AnthonyLambert i still don't get it. first time working with microcontrollers

Comment: @kai: you probably should get somewhat familiar with microcontrollers and the C programming language before carrying on.

Comment: I search for "8051 Microcontroller pdf" and found this... maybe you should take a look [8051 Microcontroller Book](http://www.iust.ac.ir/files/ee/pages/az/mazidi.pdf) Then maybe you could come back with some questions.

Comment: thanks. will definitely go thru this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very hard to tell without context. I guess following:

The `timer0` interrupt routine is called every 100th of a second. There it increments the `tick` counter which is reset to 0 as soon as it gets bigger than 3500. The `sec` counter seems to be a second counter as it is incremented every 100th call to `timer0` (which is called 100 times per second).

The `extrint` seems to be called upon some external event. It just copies the actual value of `tick` into `bt` (presumably for some further processing) and resets `tick` to 0.